# Passing params to Angular $http redirect request

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to make the GET request for some resource. In order to access it, I have to pass additional auth params in my url, e.g

```
?client_id=...&oauth_token=...
```

The problem is that whenever I send this request to the server(with all the params required), the server sends me 303 See Other response. But as far as I know, angular $http service automatically follows this redirect, BUT!!! it does not appends all the neccessary auth params with this redirect. The question is: how could I pass those auth params in redirect, without using interceptors? For those who are interested I'm sending request to

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/me/followings/11111111?oauth_token=...
```

Comment: Can you show some more code? Why dont you use headers to pass the auth params using btoa format.

Comment: @Deepanjan This is the method from my angular service http://pastebin.com/PChzdBsX